# Why does first window need a call to mainloop() while the second window doesn't

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a application that needs 2 windows. The first one, I do all the standard stuff like

```
root = tk.Tk()
...code...
root.mainloop()
```

But for my second window, I only call

```
root = tk.Tk()
```

and it works. If I do

```
root = tk.Tk()
...code...
root.mainloop()
```

it still works. Out of pure curiosity, why?

Code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror
from time import sleep

class DecompilingChecker(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.master = tk.Tk()
        self.master.withdraw()
        self.master.title("Test Program: Update")

    def check(self, file, directory):
        self.master.update()
        self.master.deiconify()

class TestProgram(object):
    pass

class GUI(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Test Program")
        tk.Text(self.master).grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.decompilingchecker = DecompilingChecker()
        self.decompilingchecker.check(None, None)

class Bridge(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        GUI(self.root)

    def run(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        bridge = Bridge()
        bridge.run()
    except Exception as e:
        showerror("Test Program: ERROR!", "An error has occurred!\n{0}".format(str(e)))
``
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not call `tk.Tk()` more than once. For additional windows, use `tk.Toplevel()`. Calling `update` is only necessary in some rare cases, your GUI is most times better off relying on the `mainloop` for the updates.

```
import tkinter as tk


class DecompilingChecker(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.title("DecompilingChecker Toplevel")

    def check(self):
        print('checking')


class Bridge(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.title("Bridge Toplevel")


class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("GUI window")
        self.bridge = Bridge(self)
        self.d_checker = DecompilingChecker(self)
        self.d_checker.check()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    GUI().mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know!